# Can ping intranet from host, but not from a container

Tags: docker

I have container, from which I am trying to reach an intranet ip.
This IP I can ping from host.

What could be the reason?

Google for example I can ping form the container.

Comment: Hope this helps - https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/221

Comment: do you have the same `/etc/resolv.conf` file in host and container?